# Quiero hacer un salto de línea en un correo que quiero enviar desde Java

Tags: java, gmail

Envío un correo automático desde Java en donde el mensaje es el siguiente

`Content= "Estimado usuario, su token de sesión es el siguiente: "+token;`

Lo que quiero es que el el correo electrónico el token aparezca debajo del texto.

Comment: Hola Omar, bienvenido, "**\n**" es lo que buscas, representa un salto de linea, puedes poner: **Content= "Estimado usuario, su token de sesión es el siguiente: \n" + token;**

Answer (score -1):

Has probado con /n?

Content= "Estimado usuario, su token de sesión es el siguiente: /n"+token;

Saludos!

Comment: Hola leandroian, gracias por colaborar, te sugiero reemplazar "/n" por "\n" que es el salto de linea... ;)